# Regex fails only on Safari

Tags: javascript, regex, safari, backtracking

I have the following simple email validation regex: `/(.+){2,}@(.+){2,}\.(.+){2,}/`

This works fine on Firefox, Chrome etc, but fails on Safari.

Why would this perfectly valid regex fail on Safari? I could not find elements in the regex that are not supported by Safari.

```
/(.+){2,}@(.+){2,}\.(.+){2,}/.test('123@abc.nl');
```

Above fails on Safari, but not on any other browser.

Comment: The regex is just bad, you should never quantify `(.+)` like that. It should be written as `/.{2,}@.{2,}\..{2,}/`

Comment: Be that as it may, the behavior should not be inconsistent between Safari and other browsers, right?

Comment: Safari really doesn't like those groups.

Comment: No, different regex engines have different tolerance wrt the catastrophic backtracking prone patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different regex engines have different tolerance to catastrophic backtracking prone patterns.

Yours is a catastrophic backtracking prone pattern as you quantify `(.+)` with the `{2,}` quantifier that makes `(.+)` match two or more times (that is, match one or more times twice or more, which makes it fail very slowly with non-matching patterns.)

If you meant to match any two or more chars, quantify the `.` pattern and not a `.+` one:

```
/.{2,}@.{2,}\..{2,}/
```

Or, use existing [email validation patterns.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression).